# how to avoid memory leaks in android

Tags: android, memory, memory-leaks

I am dynamically updating the tablelayout as shown below where  I am appending an imagebutton and a Textview for each tableRow.Whenever I launch my activity it shows only 4 rows (should display 10 actually) but if I keep break points in code and debug slowly to figure out the problem it displays all the 10 rows properly. I doubt it must be a memory problem in the code as I am getting Images from the web which I feel takes lot of memory. I tried releasing views memory after adding to the layout but it is crashing all the time.
Please let me know where I am doing wrong.

```
for (int i = 0; i < parsedExampleDataSet.getAppNameString().size(); i++)  
{  
 TableRow row = new TableRow(this);  
 TextView tv = new TextView(this);  
 tv.setText("AppName: "+ parsedExampleDataSet.getAppNameString().get(i) +"\n"     + "Description: " + parsedExampleDataSet.getDescriptionString().get(i));  
 ImageButton imgBtn = new ImageButton(this);  
 URL aURL = new URL(parsedExampleDataSet.getImageUrlString().get(i));   
 URLConnection conn = aURL.openConnection();   
 conn.connect();   
 InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();   
 BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);  
 Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis);   
 imgBtn.setImageBitmap(bm);  
 imgBtn.setBackgroundColor(color.transparent);  
 imgBtn.setTag(parsedExampleDataSet.getMarketLinkString().get(i));  
 bis.close();   
 is.close();                      
 row.addView(imgBtn);  
 row.addView(tv);  
 table.addView(row,new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));  //here table is a tablelayout object
```

}

Thanks in advance
Prathima

Comment: What is the stack trace?

Comment: How do you get parsedExampleDataSet? Isn't it parsed in separate thread? Did you try just to printout size of it?

Comment: @ania ::no its parsed in the same thread. I dint try to print size(). Will do it now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load more than one row than use ListView.

It handles all memory issues and better than TableLayout.

[here](https://github.com/thest1/LazyList) is one good example.

Comment: Thanks! I am newbie to android. Initially i tried to implement this using listview but i couldn't understand the concept properly. Thatswhy i have chosen tablelayout

Answer (score 0):

The answer seems to be located in `parsedExampleDataSet.getAppNameString().size()`:

- When you are running the program, the `for(;;)` loop iterates only 4 times
- When you are running the debugger and stepping manually, it iterates 10 times, which is according to your expectation

How is populated parsedExampleDataSet.getAppNameString()? Its size is used as the upper bound of the `for(;;)` loop, and it seems to change over the time. Should it be populated by an asynchronous process (a thread) this would explain the issue.

Feel free to add more details and let me know. I'll edit/elaborate this answer further to the new elements you'll bring.